# Polymer 1.0 Local Dom issue with this.$ selector

Tags: javascript, polymer, this, shadow-dom

I understand that we can select elements  from the local dom with the this.$ selector. However, if I have a function that fires on a button click, how would I access an element by ID within this function?

For example:

HTML:

```
 <input id = "counter" value = "10">
```

JavaScript:

```
var testButton = this.$.testButton;
$(testButton).click(function(){
   var counter = this.$.counter;
   console.log(counter.value);
}
```

The issue is that the "this.$.counter" is now referencing the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you use Polymer it doesn't change how event handlers and `this` works. `this` within your event handler corresponds to `testButton`, since it is the element that fired the `click` event, not the Polymer element.

Try this:

```
var testButton = this.$.testButton;
var counter = this.$.counter;
$(testButton).click(function(){
   console.log(counter.value);
}
```

Comment: Ah of course. Long day at work totally just brain farted there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using Polymer's onTap function instead of onClick would also solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery with polymer there is a good chance you are doing something wrong.

```
<button on-tap='foo'>
```

...

```
Polymer({
```

...

```
  foo: function(event){
    console.log(this.$.counter);
  }
});
```